# Error when installing Discord Anti Spam package with NPM

Tags: npm

I need help with this error its annoying and I did everything I possibly could like updating Discord.js. It seems to still say its not in the registry. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong here or what I am missing?

```
npm ERR! 404  'discord-anti-spam-development@^2.4.1' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
```

Comment: The package doesn't exist in the registry. The error message already tells you the two options you have.

Answer (score 0):

You might looking for [`discord-anti-spam`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/discord-anti-spam) package, not `discord-anti-spam-development`

Install command should be:

```
npm install discord-anti-spam
```